# How to get data from a weather station into Excel or Accel

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, import

I've been trying to import the data from my weather station into an Excel worksheet but failed miserably trying to do so. I've been able to download the data to a Json file and I've been reading trough this website for hours and tried many sugested solutions I've downloaded the JsonConverter.bas application added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, but I've not been able to get it working. It should be simply, but not for me. The data set is quit large about 720 lines each day.
I've used a online Json viewer to look at the data and that data looks fine, The only data I can get is "observations" and that's what I don't need.

I would like to retrieve row's of data all related to a certain time stamp so I can make graphs and calculate the Solar input, rain, max temp, for a day and so on.

I just need to get the principle of retrieving the data. Each single record should, in the end, have 37 items
This is what I've done so far (amongst others):

```
 Dim Observations As Dictionary
 Dim Metric As Dictionary
 Dim httpObject As Object
 Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' modified station and API-key, data is below
 sURL = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/history/all?stationId=MyStation&format=json&units=m&date=20200606&apiKey=02d56c*******b956c8555295f6be3"

 sRequest = sURL
 httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False
 httpObject.Send
 sgetresult = httpObject.responseText

 MsgBox sgetresult

 Dim oJSON As Object
 Set oJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJSON(httpObject.responseText)

 For Each Observations In oJSON("observations")
' this does print data
 Debug.Print Observations("uvHigh")
 Next

For Each Metric In oJSON("observations")("metric")
'this does not print data
  Debug.Print Metric("pressureMax")
Next



End Sub
```

Sample data:

```
{"observations":[{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:04:47Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:04:47","epoch":1591394687,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":193,"humidityHigh":90,"humidityLow":89,"humidityAvg":89,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":6,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":9,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":6,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.22,"pressureTrend":0.00,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:09:51Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:09:51","epoch":1591394991,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":195,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":7,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":5,"windgustHigh":11,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":7,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":8,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.11,"pressureTrend":0.00,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:14:55Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:14:55","epoch":1591395295,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":196,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":6,"windspeedLow":3,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":7,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.52,"pressureMin":988.11,"pressureTrend":-1.27,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:19:59Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:19:59","epoch":1591395599,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":195,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":5,"windspeedLow":1,"windspeedAvg":3,"windgustHigh":7,"windgustLow":2,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":9,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.22,"pressureTrend":1.27,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:24:47Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:24:47","epoch":1591395887,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":202,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":7,"windspeedLow":1,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":9,"windgustLow":2,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.22,"pressureTrend":1.34,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:29:51Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:29:51","epoch":1591396191,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":194,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":6,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":7,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.01,"pressureTrend":-3.81,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:34:55Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:34:55","epoch":1591396495,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":204,"humidityHigh":88,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":9,"windspeedLow":1,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":11,"windgustLow":2,"windgustAvg":6,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":7,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.11,"pressureTrend":3.81,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:39:59Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:39:59","epoch":1591396799,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":206,"humidityHigh":88,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":5,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":3,"windgustHigh":7,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.52,"pressureMin":988.22,"pressureTrend":-2.54,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:44:47Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:44:47","epoch":1591397087,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":200,"humidityHigh":88,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":6,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":9,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.01,"pressureTrend":-1.34,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:49:51Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:49:51","epoch":1591397391,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":199,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":6,"windspeedLow":2,"windspeedAvg":4,"windgustHigh":7,"windgustLow":4,"windgustAvg":5,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":9,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.32,"pressureMin":988.01,"pressureTrend":1.27,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:54:55Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:54:55","epoch":1591397695,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":198,"humidityHigh":89,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":9,"windspeedLow":3,"windspeedAvg":5,"windgustHigh":13,"windgustLow":5,"windgustAvg":8,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":7,"windchillAvg":8,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.42,"pressureMin":988.11,"pressureTrend":0.00,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}},{"stationID":"MyStation","tz":"Europe/Brussels","obsTimeUtc":"2020-06-05T22:59:59Z","obsTimeLocal":"2020-06-06 00:59:59","epoch":1591397999,"lat":50.381358,"lon":5.73342,"solarRadiationHigh":0.00,"uvHigh":0.0,"winddirAvg":201,"humidityHigh":88,"humidityLow":88,"humidityAvg":88,"qcStatus":1,"metric":{"tempHigh":9,"tempLow":9,"tempAvg":9,"windspeedHigh":8,"windspeedLow":3,"windspeedAvg":5,"windgustHigh":9,"windgustLow":5,"windgustAvg":7,"dewptHigh":7,"dewptLow":7,"dewptAvg":7,"windchillHigh":9,"windchillLow":8,"windchillAvg":8,"heatindexHigh":9,"heatindexLow":9,"heatindexAvg":9,"pressureMax":988.22,"pressureMin":987.91,"pressureTrend":-2.54,"precipRate":0.00,"precipTotal":0.00}}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried power query.. Import json

Comment: Why not post the code you tried and describe the problems you had when running it? If you parse that result into an object `JSON` then that object will be a dictionary, and the key "observations" will refer to a Collection of dictionaries, each with keys "stationID", "tz", etc

Comment: I prefer to get this done in VBA as this is what I know best. I need to do more with the data.

Comment: I've edited the post with some code I've used to get the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After keeping working on the problem, I've found the working solution.
It simply turns out I have to point to the additional Dictionary and add the correct key to get the value out.

```
Dim Observations As Dictionary
Dim Metric As Dictionary
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 sURL = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/history/all?stationId=IKALMT4&format=json&units=m&date=20200606&apiKey=02d56c8555294f6b956c8555295f6be3"

 sRequest = sURL
 httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False
 httpObject.Send
 sgetresult = httpObject.responseText

 MsgBox sgetresult

 Dim oJSON As Object
 Set oJSON = JsonConverter.ParseJSON(httpObject.responseText)

 For Each Observations In oJSON("observations")
    Debug.Print Observations("uvHigh")
    Debug.Print Observations("humidityAvg")

' Pointing to the right dictionary helps to get the data out.
    Debug.Print Observations("metric")("pressureMax")
 Next

End Sub
```